# Convert hex value from SQL Server to datetime in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, hex, converters

I need to convert 8 bytes from a hexadecimal value to a new datetime in C#. The function should do the same as it does in SQL Server.

I have the hexadecimal value as a string "0000AC0500000000" or a list of bytes:

```
["0", "0", "172", "5", "0", "0", "0", " 0 ",]
```

From that I need to obtain the date "2020-07-27 00:00:00:000". The convert of the SQL Server works perfectly to recover up to milliseconds with only 8 bytes. As shown [convert function in SQL Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klQaR.png)

Comment: Curious.  Why do you have it in this form in the first place?

Comment: Like @Matt, I have some real questions here - mostly "what was wrong with the SQL server date/time types?"

Comment: recovery binary date from disk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following

```
            string input = "0000AC0500000000";

            int daysFrom1900 = int.Parse(input.Substring(0,8),NumberStyles.HexNumber);
            int ticksFromMidnight = int.Parse(input.Substring(8), NumberStyles.HexNumber);
            DateTime year1900 = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1);
            DateTime date = year1900.AddDays(daysFrom1900).AddTicks(ticksFromMidnight*(10/3.0));
```

Comment: this is correct, but to add the milliseconds it must be done like this (sql server):

DateTime date = year1900.AddDays(daysFrom1900).AddTicks(ticksFromMidnight*(10/3.0));